# what's the word for joining a university class when I am not a student there

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Image I go to my friend's university and join one of their class(by join I mean just sit in the classroom and listening to the lecture)

Is there a phrase/word for this type of behavior or situation?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Several things are unclear. When you say *go to my friend's university*, do you mean you are enrolled at the same university, or that you are visiting your friend's university? Second, when you say *join*, do you mean you attend the classes regularly with your attendance acknowledged by the instructor, or that you simply drop in once or a few times on an ad hoc basis, without the professor or institution's explicit assent? If the latter, there's no special term; you're just a *visitor*.

Comment: @choster Hi, thanks for the reply.  Sorry I was not clear. It is just a one time thing. I am not enrolled in the course nor do I attend the course regularly. I guess my question is, If I just show up in the class and the prof asks me if he or she knows me, what should I say to express that I am just a `visitor`?

Comment: You would simply say *visitor*. Is there a special word for this situation in your mother tongue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase to use for informally joining a lecture, meeting, etc. is "**to sit in on**".

> I will **sit in on** your class today, since I have nothing else to do.
>
> The topic looked interesting, so I **sat in on** yesterday's lecture.

The phrase is quite idiomatic and common among native speakers.

As Ross mentioned in another answer. When there is a formal arrangement to attend a class without necessarily performing all the work or receiving a grade, the phrase would be "to audit".

Answer (score 1):

EDIT TO ADD: This answer is wrong. It would apply if someone attended all lectures for a course, but not for just one lecture.

The expression for that is 'audit'. You can say, "I audit this class."

This is from the [M-WD definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/audit) of 'audit' as a verb:

> to attend (a course) without working for or expecting to receive
>   formal credit, e.g. *audited a foreign language course*

The expression is idiomatic, i.e. does not make literal sense. The meaning is nothing like the more usual mean of an accountant checking the financial accounts of a business.

Comment: *Auditing* is a formal arrangement where you are allowed to sit in on the class, but are not enrolled in it for academic credit. Sitting in on a lecture with a friend is not auditing, and dropping in for a visit does not make you an auditor.

Comment: Separately, the term *audit* was adopted from the Latin *audiro*, *audire* meaning *to listen*; if anything, to attend a lecture as an observer makes more "literal sense" than to examine ledgers in discussing auditors and auditing.

Comment: @choster  Agreed. I didn't read the question carefully enough and answered as if the sitting in was for an entire course, not one lecture.

Comment: I would just [edit] the answer to provide context— I don't see any need to preserve the "wrong" version as it had received no upvotes.